# Apple News Preview - Simulator stopped working

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, apple-news

I am currently testing the Apple News JSON format using `XCode` / `News Preview` / `Simulator` and randomly running into a new error that was not occurring prior to today.

I am attempting to load the `article.json` file into the `News Preview` app (it's been working up until today).  The `article.json` file gets successfully loaded with no errors in the console but the `Simulator` is claiming that the channel is not available for me.  Here is what the error message on the `Simulator` reads:

---

**Channel Unavailable**

This channel isn't currently available in your region.

---

The `News Preview` and `Simulator` were working just fine until today.  I have tried re-installing `XCode` and `News Preview` (and `Simulator` because I re-installed `XCode`) but the problem persists.  Other colleagues of mine are now experiencing the same problem.

I tried also clearing all the content in the `Simulator` and tried wiping the device clean and also tried going to the "Debug" menu in `Simulator` and setting the Location specifically there, as well, without any success.

Is there a way to fix this or is there a way to know if there was a recent developer push to the `Simulator` code base?

Just to add a bit more detail, I am attempting to load the official `Apple News` article preview files, not my own `article.json` files (I tried loading my own json files, as well).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please file a radar with the output of `xcrun simctl diagnose` and attach the files you're trying to use if possible, then reply with the radar #.

Comment: im getting the following error at this point when running that command: `xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH`

Comment: That is very strange because `simctl` has shipped with Xcode for several major releases. Is Xcode selected? Check `xcode-select -p`, is it the Xcode you expected?

Comment: @russbishop, it seems that this might be relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-invalid-active-developer-path

Answer (score 2):

Hey I also just had this issue and have been troubleshooting since yesterday. Not sure what is causing it, but it only happens for my on devices simulators from iPhone 7 and newer.

Try running the preview on iPhone 6 or an older-gen iPad, etc... that's working for me.

Comment: The funny thing is that even after I got it working on my 2011 Macbook Pro, I bought a brand new Macbook Pro today and when I try to load articles on any of the simulators, the simulator tells me that the "link or story is invalid".  I even put in the Publisher ID.  I think this is related to Xcode or some sort of License Agreement with Xcode command line tools or something to that effect. I'll update again once I figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution **on only one of my machines** was to enter the Publisher ID into the News Preview application, which is the first thing that is asked when launching the News Preview app. After entering the Publisher ID, everything seemed to return to normal - for all of my colleagues and I.

See my comment above about my new macbook and the new problem it is having.